# How can get a scroll event work in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, scroll

I currently have this piece of code:

```
canvas.onmousewheel = scroll;

function scroll(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var mousex = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mousey = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    var wheel = parseInt(event.wheelDelta, 10) / 120; //n or -n

    var zoom = 1 + wheel / 2;

    [... do some action on canvas ...]
};
```

Sadly, this doesn't work in Firefox. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mousewheel):

> Gecko doesn't have a plan to implement this event due to legacy event
>   type and non-standard.

How can I get my code work for Chrome and Firefox?

edit: The full code is [here](http://martin-thoma.com/html5/polynom-interpolation.htm) (one file, about 550 LOC)

Comment: firefox onscroll event works fine. You can get easily the offset in the event object in event.pageY my problem now is actually with chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following link

From the page:
[onmousewheel event and Firefox's equivalent](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml)

```
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x

if (document.attachEvent) //if IE (and Opera depending on user setting)
    document.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, function(e){alert('Mouse wheel movement detected!')})
else if (document.addEventListener) //WC3 browsers
    document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, function(e){alert('Mouse wheel movement detected!')}, false)
```

Comment: I also had to use `event.detail` instead of `event.wheelDelta`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and I wrote code to use different events depending on the browser. Certainly jQuery or other frameworks would do it easily, but I am a Vanilla Javascript programmer.

For chrome: **onmousewheel** and **document.body.scrollTop** works.
For firefox: **onscroll** and **event.pageY** do the same.

```
if( Browser.chrome){
    window.onmousewheel=function(e){      
      if( document.body.scrollTop > 60){
       /* code to run on scrolled window */
      } else {
      /* code to run when on top */
       }
    };
} else {
   window.onscroll=function(e){
     if(e.pageY > 60){
      /* code to run on scrolled window */
     } else {
      /* code to run when on top */
     }
  };
}
```

Browsers library available at http://software.sitesbr.net/utils/